# Azure EventHub - EventHubClient.Send() results in NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, azure, nullreferenceexception

Short version: `NullReferenceException` when using `EventHubClient.SendBatch` to send data to EventHub. Why is the connection being dropped?

Longer explanation:

I'm trying to send data to `EventHub`, using the `SendBatch` method from `EventHubClient` class in C#. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient)

The batch size is 100 json objects, and should not be too large. I've encountered the same problem with both bigger and smaller batch sizes. I've also tried using `Send()`, to send object one by one. Same result.

This works great 99% of the time, but sometimes results in a `NullReferenceException`, leaving the following stacktrace:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageSender.RetrySenderEventDataAsyncResu
    lt.<>c.<.ctor>b__5_0(EventData e)
      at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate
    )
      at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageSender.RetrySenderEventDataAsyncResu
    lt..ctor(MessageSender sender, TrackingContext trackingContext, IEnumerable`1 me
    ssages, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
      at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageSender.BeginSendEventData(TrackingCo
    ntext trackingContext, IEnumerable`1 eventDatas, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback
    callback, Object state)
      at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.EventHubClient.SendBatch(IEnumerable`1 even
    tDataList)
```

I've tried to implement a retry policy, both using 
`EventHubClient.RetryPolicy = RetryPolicy.Default;` and by manually doing a recursive method call with `Thread.Sleep(n)`, to give the connection time to get re-established.

Sometimes the connection goes back up after 10 seconds, sometimes after 60 seconds, and usually never (or until my recursive call of the method hits a `StackOverflowException`, after about 30 mins, but depending on how long the thread is put to sleep). Logically, I can't have this unstable part of my system.

Anyone have any idea why this exception occurs, and if it is due to a connection drop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here turned out to be an overloaded EventHub.

For every 100th batch, wait 0.5 seconds. For every NullReferenceException, wait 2 seconds before trying again with the same data. More than 100 retries could be needed before the connection is back up. I tried with exponential waiting time, which was not successful in my case (ended up waiting for several hours, and still no connection).

And of course - use an eternal while loop instead of a recursive call in `C#`. This prevents the `StackOverflowException`. (Rookie mistake).

Working code:

```
public bool SendMessageAsList(List<EventData list) 
{
while(true)
{
    var batchList = new List<EventData>();
    for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i + 100)
    try
    {
        if (i % 10000)
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        batchList = list.Skip(i).Take(100).ToList();
        EventHubClient.SendBatch(batchList);
        // Gets here at success
        list = list.Skip(100).ToList();
        if (batchList.Count < 100)
            break;
    }
    catch (NullReferanceException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        Thread.Sleep(2000)
}
}
```